# How to reconfigure oracle XE 18c

Tags: linux, configuration, database-administration, oracle-xe

I'm trying to run connect to oracle xe database on an oracle linux with python (cx_Oracle package), but I cannot remember the username neither the password for the connect string. I've already searched for tutorials to change the database password but I can't find my `ORACLE_HOME` path thus I don't have access to SQLPLUS.

So what I need is, a way to reconfigure the database so i can set the password again. The problem is that when I run `sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure` the output is Oracle Dabase instance XE is already configured.

The posts that I found about reconfiguring the database here on stackoverflow don't seem to work either.

Comment: Some generic tips: To find the SID of the DB, look at /etc/oratab.  To set your environment, run 'source /usr/local/bin/oraenv' and then enter the SID.  If you do this as the 'oracle' OS user you will then be able to connect to the DB using 'AS SYSDBA' without needing a password.  You can then change user passwords.